# elasticsearch/Kibana list field as "?", although it is "text" in index, why?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

I am adding documents to an elastic search 6.1 index using the python elasticsearch module. The data is json and that works nicely.

Before adding the data, I generate an additional field 'indexing_results' that contains a list of topics.

I find that field in the index (looking via a Kibana interface) but the type is not "t" (text) but "?" and I can't find out what makes elastic search / Kibana assume this.

[image]

When asking Kibana what the type of the new field is in the interface it tells me it is text:

[image]

With the type being "?" it seems I can't use it in Kibana visualisations - it is simply not offered as a field from which to construct charts. etc.

How can Kibana / elasticsearch be convinced to consider the "indexing_results" field as "text"?

Comment: It's not clear to me, why yo said that indexing_results is type "?" , in your first image I can't see indexing_results field

Comment: Hmm, strange: The image that I added shows that there is a "t" in front of most of the fields but not in front of the "indexing_results" : This one is preceeded by "?" and that seems to have consequences: Can't create visualisations using this etc etc. But the hint from Tyler below solves the issue. Before reindexing, I am supposed to refresh. Not is is working. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Try to refresh the index pattern. Management > Index Pattern, then there is a refresh button on the top right.

Comment: That did it: After a refresh, the indexing_results are "t" as expected. Thanks! Issue solved.